# Which Accessibility APIs can be used to enable Chrome and Firefox? UIA does not work well and breaks often

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, accessibility-api, uia

We are writing something like an Assistive User Agent, which reads screens using Accessibility API and provides help to users. 
UIA does not seem to be natively supported by Chrome and Firefox. This is causing our implementation to break when Chrome or Firefox updates. 
What would be the accessibility apis that work on both Chrome and Firefox other than Microsoft UIA.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome actually has support for iAccessible, but it is not turned on by default and needs to be operated manually on the following page.

`chrome://accessibility/`

Answer (score 0):

The accessibility APIs implemented in *both* Chrome and Firefox on Windows are **Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA)** and **IAccessible2**. See

- Chromium: [Accessibility Technical Documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility): this document claims complete support for MSAA/IAccessible and IAccessible2, and very limited support for IAccessibleEx and UI Automation.
- MDN - Mozilla Firefox: [AT APIs Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/AT-APIs): this page mentions support for MSAA and IAccessible2 on Windows but does not mention UI Automation. See also [MSAA Roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/AT-APIs/MSAA/Roles) and [IAccessible2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/IAccessible2) on MDN.